# What does it mean for consonant/ vowel sound to shift?

Tags: sound-change

In this [site](https://lingvist.com/course/learn-german-online/resources/german-verb-conjugation/),

> With weak verbs, consonant sounds shift, often in the form of suffixes (endings) added onto the stem.

> In the case of strong verbs, the vowel sound shifts, often within the stem.

What exactly does it mean for the sound to shift?

Comment: “To shift” means “to alternate, change, become different”. For example, the vowel sound [uː] shifts into [iː] when ‘tooth’ and ‘goose’ become plural ‘teeth’ and ‘geese’.

Comment: I have no idea what they mean by consonants ‘shifting’ in weak verbs – in general, consonants do not shift in regular verbs in German or English. An extra consonant is added on to the end of the verb, but none of the consonants in the root shift (except for some automatic assimilation, like German _reisen_ with intervocalic [z] vs _reiste_ with preconsonantal [s], or English _squeezed_ with [d] vs _fleeced_ with [t]). It makes sense to say that strong vowels are characterised by vowels shifting, but the statement about weak verbs is nonsense.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think the site views assimilation as "consonant shift" and doesn't try to distinguish it from umlaut or ablaut. All inflection and root changes will be strange to English learners, who by and large don't understand how common it is in English.

Answer (score 2):

I see that this is from a German course. The statement that "In the case of strong verbs, the vowel sound shifts, often within the stem" is fairly straightforward. It says that in verbs like "ich fahre - ich fuhr" the vowel in the stem changes ("shifts"), in this case from /a/ to /u/. I do not, however, see why it claims that this "shift" is "OFTEN within the stem". Where else is it supposed to shift?

The statement that "With weak verbs, consonant sounds shift, often in the form of suffixes (endings) added onto the stem" does not make any sense. In words like "ich suche - ich suchte" nothing is "shifting"; the past tense is made simply by adding -t to the stem. I suggest that the author of this course does not know what (s)he is talking about.

Comment: Also, when is a weak verb in German _not_ inflected by adding suffixes onto the stem? Any verb that is conjugated in other ways than suffixation are, by definition, not weak.

Comment: There are a few weak verbs with *Rückumlaut* like *brennen, brannte, gebrannt* or *rennen, rannte, gerannt*, but I wouldn't take the quoted website too seriously and I doubt they meant this here.

Comment: Calling verbs "weak" and "strong" instead of "regular" and "irregular" is already unnecessarily confusing; they're not opposed, each with its own idiosyncrasies. One is all idiosyncrasy and the other is just normal inflection.

Comment: @jlawler Lumping strong and truly irregular verbs together as the same group is also unnecessarily confusing for learners (and native speakers don’t care either way). Strong verbs follow patterns – complex patterns sometimes, yes, but patterns nonetheless – which the truly irregular verbs do not.

Comment: Well, yes, but a language learner doesn't need that level of sophistication at first.